# Kotlin windowed function to coroutine and execute all at once

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

How to execute batches all at once in a parallel way.

I have the following code:

```
val batches = list
     .windowed(100, 100, true)
     .map { Process(it) }
```

Is there a way to parallel execute all patches each in a coroutine at once?
Is there a better way than

```
  withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            batches.map { launch{}}.joinAll()
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code sample is exactly how it should be done - simply use `map()` or `foreach()` with `async()` or `launch()`.

Note that `withContext()` automatically waits for all children, so if you don't need any result from each batch (it doesn't seem so), you don't need to use `joinAll()` and `map()`:

```kotlin
withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    batches.foreach { launch{} }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried doing that, but I have to wait for the result of all of them as well. the right way of doing it in java was ForkJoinTask.invokeAll(batches)
as method Process inherit java RecursiveAction()
IS there a way to convent that so the code works because the current code is not working with batches.foreach { launch{} }

Comment: Do you need to wait for their **result** or only to wait for them to finish? I ask because in your code sample you don't return any kind of result from processing of batches. If you need to only wait for them to finish succesfully, then as I already said in the answer, my code sample already does this.

Comment: Wait for them to finish mainly no need for a result.
When I converted the Process class to function and removed RecursiveAction()
It worked.
Seems that the first coroutine takes sometime because of the withContext

Comment: @I.A, maybe you need to be more explicit about what's inside your `launch` call. As long as you aren't calling asynchronous code in there, it should be waiting for the work to finish with the above code or your original code.

Comment: @broot launch actually execute function that loop over the data. weirdly thread is 4 times faster than using coroutines